# How to pass a subset of a collection to a C# method?

Tags: c#, .net

In C++, anytime I want to process some range of items I do something like this:

```
template<class Iterator>
void method(Iterator range_begin, Iterator range_end);
```

Is there such a convenient way to do this in C#, not only for `System.Array` but for other collection classes as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of any at the moment, but using LINQ you can easily create an `IEnumerable<T>` representing a part of your collection.

As I understand it, the C# way is to see a part of a collection as a collection itself, and make your `method` to work on this sequence. This idea allows the method to be ignorant to whether it's working on the whole collection or its part.

Examples:

```
void method(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{ ... }

// from 2-nd to 5-th item:
method(original.Skip(1).Take(4));
// all even items:
method(original.Where(x => x % 2 == 0));
// everything till the first 0
method(original.TakeWhile(x => x != 0));
// everything
method(original);
```

etc.

Compare this to C++:

```
// from 2-nd to 5-th item:
method(original.begin() + 1, original.begin() + 5);
// everything
method(original.begin(), original.end());
// other two cannot be coded in this style in C++
```

In C++, your code calculates iterators in order to pass them around, and mark the beginning and the end of your sequence. In C#, you pass lightweight `IEnumerable`s around. Due to the lazy evaluation this should have no overhead.

Answer (score 8):

```
// ...
using System.Linq;

IEnumerable<T> GetSubset<T>( IEnumerable<T> collection, int start, int len )
{
    // error checking if desired
    return collection.Skip( start ).Take( len );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use LINQ, take a look at `Skip` and `Take`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use IEnumerable<> and pass in your values as a LINQ query?

```
void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> workSet) {
    foreach (var workItem in workSet) {
        doWorkWithItem(workItem);
    }
}

var dataset = yourArray.SkipWhile(i=>i!=startItem).TakeWhile(i=>i!=endItem);
MyMethod(dataset);

var pagedSet = yourArray.Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(pageSize);
MyMethod(pagedSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't that be the same as using LAMBDA expression to subset your list?

```
public myClass {
    public int Year { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

then...

```
List<myClass> allClasses = db.GetClasses();
IEnumerable<myClass> subsetClasses = allClasses.where(x => x.Year >= 1990 && x.Year <= 2000);

processSubset(subsetClasses);
```

or you could use `skip()` and `take()` just like in a database if you want to process `n` items in the collection without a given argument.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of collection you're using. Some have more capabilities than others. Using a list, you can do something like this:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst = lst.Where(str => str == "Harry" || str == "John" || str == "Joey").ToList();
```